# Missing libstdc++ when installing taglib-ruby gem on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, libstdc++, taglib-ruby

I'm trying to install [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) but keep getting the same errors:

```
xyz@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install taglib-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing taglib-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... no
You must have libstdc++ installed.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-tag-dir
    --without-tag-dir
    --with-tag-include
    --without-tag-include=${tag-dir}/include
    --with-tag-lib
    --without-tag-lib=${tag-dir}/lib
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taglib-ruby-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taglib-ruby-0.6.0/ext/taglib_base/gem_make.out
```

mkmf.log says the following:

```
have_library: checking for main() in -lstdc++... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/sw/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/sw/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1 -lstdc++  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: /*top*/
4: int main() {return 0;}
5: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/sw/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1 -lstdc++  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: /*top*/
4: int main() {return 0;}
5: int t() { main(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

I followed the instructions in the readme, installing `libtag1-dev` and double checked if I had libstdc++ installed which I do (I even looked in the Ubuntu Software Center if I missed a file).
The only similar issue I found was [this one](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby/issues/7) but I already tried explictly defining the `opt-dir` and `opt-include` which didn't help either.

I have to admit that I am not really familiar with the topic or even Ubuntu, so it might as well be possible that I simply overlooked or totally missed something obvious about the error message.

Comment: Try installing 'build-essentials', it should come with a C++ development environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing libstdc++ during gem install id3lib-ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485266/missing-libstdc-during-gem-install-id3lib-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev

Fedora/RHEL: sudo yum install taglib-devel

Brew: brew install taglib

MacPorts: sudo port install taglib